# How can I access to content of Tensor in custom loss of Keras model

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, autoencoder, loss

I am building an Autoencoder using Keras model. I want to built a custom loss in the form of `alpha* L2(x, x_pred) + beta * L1(day_x, day_x_pred)`. The second term of L1 loss to penalize regarding to time (day_x is a day number). The day is the first feature in my input data. 
my input data is of the form  `['day', 'beta', 'sigma', 'gamma', 'mu']`.

the input x is of shape (batch_size, number of features) and I have 5 features. 
So my question is how to extract the first feature from `x and x_pred` to compute `L1(t_x, t_x_pred)`.
This is my current loss function :

```
def loss_function(x, x_predicted):
    #with tf.compat.v1.Session() as sess:   print(x.eval())  
    return 0.7 * K.square(x- x_predicted) + 0.3 * K.abs(x[:,1]-x_predicted[:,1])
```

but this didn't work for me.

Comment: why didn't it work?

Comment: it didn't work when i uncomment the L1 part, I think i am making a wrong slicing

Comment: which is the error you receive?

Comment: InvalidArgumentError:  Incompatible shapes: [50,5] vs. [50]
  [[node BroadcastGradientArgs_7]]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this is the loss you need...

you have to compute the means of your errors

```
def loss_function(x, x_predicted):

    get_day_true = x[:,0] # get day column
    get_day_pred = x_predicted[:,0] # get day column                           
    day_loss = K.mean(K.abs(get_day_true - get_day_pred))
    all_loss = K.mean(K.square(x - x_predicted))

    return 0.7 * all_loss + 0.3 * day_loss
```

otherwise, you have to insert a dimensionality

```
def loss_function(x, x_predicted):

    get_day_true = x[:,0] # get day column
    get_day_pred = x_predicted[:,0] # get day column                           
    day_loss = K.abs(get_day_true - get_day_pred)
    all_loss = K.square(x - x_predicted)

    return 0.7 * all_loss + 0.3 * tf.expand_dims(day_loss, axis=-1)
```

use the loss when you compile your model

```
model.compile('adam', loss=loss_function)
```

Comment: Thank you that what i am looking for!!

Comment: Great! Don't forget to accept it as answer and upvote